# Quick Sort Algorithm UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

Error : builtins.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 448: invalid start byte

```
def quicksort(Info):
        lesser=[]
        greater=[]
        if len(Info) <= 1:
                return Info
        for swap in Info[1:]:
                if swap < Info[0]:
                        lesser.append(swap)
                else:
                        greater.append(swap)
        print(quicksort(lesser)+Info[0:1]+quicksort(greater))   

a= ['Babado Novo: Ver-te Mar', 'Natas es Satan', 'All Out War', '"The Cell"', '¡Ja me maaten...!', '"Formula 1: BBC Sport"', 'Ambos mundos', 'Angels with Dirty Faces', 'Barrio Gangsters', 'The LXD: The Secrets of the Ra', '90 Jahre Burgenland', 'La guitarra muda', 'Alma gitana', 'Depravada', 'Especial humor: Vaya... y vuelta', 'Entre las patas de los caballos', 'Fillet of Soul', 'Llamada', 'All of Her', "Hustler's Untrue Hollywood Stories: Angelina vs. Jennifer", 'Black Tranny Whackers 12', '"Davno ne videlis"', 'Anna II', '"The American Experience"', 'Meus Prêmios Nick 2012', 'Possessed', 'Holzapfel weiß alles', 'Lightspeed University: Cheerleader Power', 'Kid Millions', 'Monster High', '"Big Brother\'s Bit on the Side"', '"Britain\'s Got Talent"', "Heut' kommt's drauf an", "Buffalo Jill's on DVD 2004: Swimsuit Edition", '"Sigue, sigue Plàstic"', '"Move Like Michael Jackson"']

quicksort(a)
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a bit more context to help you out. Also you seem to have "unusual" characters in some of the strings you might want to take a look into that and do some research on the coding/encoding in python

Comment: That sounds a lot like the problem is solely in the `a = [...` line and has nothing to do with your quicksort implementation.

Comment: [this could help you why](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Answer (score 1):

first, add `#coding=utf8` to the top of your script file,

second, save your file as utf-8, it may be ANSI by default.

then I get error running your code:

```
['"Big Brother\'s Bit on the Side"', '"Britain\'s Got Talent"']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\a.py", line 23, in <module>
    quicksort(a)
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\a.py", line 19, in quicksort
    print(quicksort(lesser)+Info[0:1]+quicksort(greater))
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\a.py", line 19, in quicksort
    print(quicksort(lesser)+Info[0:1]+quicksort(greater))
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\a.py", line 19, in quicksort
    print(quicksort(lesser)+Info[0:1]+quicksort(greater))
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\a.py", line 19, in quicksort
    print(quicksort(lesser)+Info[0:1]+quicksort(greater))
  File "D:\Documents\Desktop\a.py", line 19, in quicksort
    print(quicksort(lesser)+Info[0:1]+quicksort(greater))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'
```